# Как могут работать не переопределённые методы интерфейсов?

Tags: java, ооп, интерфейс, полиморфизм, переопределение

Код:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\1.txt");
System.out.println(path.getFileName());
```

Вывод:

```
1.txt
```

Как это работает, если я использую метод `getFileName()` интерфейса `Path`? У метода ведь нет реализации. Как он обрезает мне путь до имени? Где происходит магия?

Comment: `path` ссылается на объект класса, который реализует интерфейс - полиморфизм подтипов  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обьект, который реализует интерфейс `Path` является `WindowsPath` на Windows платформе. В имплементации возвращается подстрока от последнего символа `'\'` ([код 92](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4)).

```
 public Path getFileName() {
    int var1 = this.path.length();
    if(var1 == 0) {
      return this;
    } else if(this.root.length() == var1) {
      return null;
    } else {
      int var2 = this.path.lastIndexOf(92);
      if(var2 < this.root.length()) {
        var2 = this.root.length();
      } else {
        ++var2;
      }

      return new WindowsPath(this.getFileSystem(), WindowsPathType.RELATIVE, "", 
                       this.path.substring(var2));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Получается, что при вызове Paths.get метод FileSystems.getDefault() возвращает объект WindowsPath потому, что это реализация java-машины под Windows. Теперь понятно, не мог уловить эту связь между интерфейсом и реализацией.

Comment: Реализация интерфейса может быть любой, а в данном случае она привязана к ос Windows.